# TemplateField HeaderText ASP

Tags: asp.net, controltemplate, editmode, headertext

I want HeaderText to be displayed only when Edit Mode is active

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
     <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadControl" runat="server" />
     </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

I don't have Insert Template And I want header text to be displayed in only during edit mode

Comment: **Blake**  Your Code snippet helped me it changes successfully when I click Edit, but when I click Edit once more `grd.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text` becomes default again as 
`(e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)` returns false

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so would be to subscribe to the RowDataBound (assuming you are using a GridView). Check if a Row is in the Edit state, and update the corresponding header text for the Cell.

```
protected void grd_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
    {
        grd.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "Upload a File"; // Cell 0 in this case may need to be changed to match your Cell.
    }
}
```